# AWS - DynamoDB table visualization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, visualization, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

Please what is the best or recommended way how to visualize data from the DynamoDB table ? We need to create some simple dashboard with graphs connected to data table on the AWS account.

We prefer to use one of the services from AWS to keep everything in one place. I read about the QuickSight but it would be great to know some experience.

Comment: AWS Dynamo Workbench has some visualizations

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/workbench.html

Comment: Also see this question about DynamoDB, Athena, and Quicksight: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57775511/visualize-dynamodb-data-in-aws-quicksight

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visualize DynamoDB data in AWS Quicksight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57775511/visualize-dynamodb-data-in-aws-quicksight)

Comment: Thanks, yes it does. We will use QuickSight and the question you sent will be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use quicksight to visualize your table by using the Athena-DynamoDB connector. This will allow you to use DynamoDB as a table source in Athena which can then act as a source for Quicksight.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connectors-dynamodb.html